# Count the number of subset containg 1's

Tags: c, algorithm, optimization

There is bitset of lengt N (it would be about 500-700). I need to get the count of every subset containing only 1's

### Example

N = 32

Set = 0**11**0**111**00**1**0**1**00**1111**0**11**00**111**000**1**0**1**

Out = { 
[1] = 4,
[2] = 2,
[3] = 2,
[4] = 1,
[5] = 0,
...
[32] = 0
}

```
void get_count(int tab[], int len) {
int *out = calloc(1, sizeof(*out) * INT_BIT * len);
int i, j, k;
int cur;
int count = 0;

for(i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    cur = tab[i];
    for(j = 0; j < INT_BIT; j++) { 
        count += (cur & 1);
        if(!(cur & 1)) { 
            out[count]++; 
            count = 0; 
        }
        cur >>= 1;
    }
}

for(i = 0; i < INT_BIT * len; i++) {
    printf("%d ", out[i]);
}
printf("\n");
free(out);
}
```

This simple operation will be executed about billions times. Iterate over every bit is just too slow. How to optimizing this algorithm?

Comment: I don't really get, how [1]=4, because I can see a lot more than 4 length-1-subsets containing only 1's... (18, to be specific). The same for [2] and [3]...

Comment: I think You need to think about the bigger picture. How obount modifying the counts array while updating bitmasks, or somesuch? You won't get dramatic improvenments with the problem stated - the LUT approach looks like a definite looser. Maybe You can provide some broader context?

Comment: They're really sub *strings* rather than subsets, right? Otherwise the rest of the question doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use a lookup table choosing an appropriate dimension (maybe 8 bits or 16 bits keys).

In this lookup table I would associate every key with 4 values:

- number of 1 bits attached to the left side
- number of 1 bits attached to the right side
- number of subsets in the middle not attached to anything
- sizes of subsets in the middle

For example you could associate the key `11011011` with 2,2,2 so that you know that a left adjacent byte with at least 1 bit attached to the right side  will contain a subset which is its size + 2 (the left attached length of the current byte) and so on.

You would need to find a way to

- manage more than 1 subset in the same key (eg `01011010`)
- manage a key which has all 1s so that you will have to consider left byte and right byte and add the key length as part of the subset length.

but every key which has 0 on the first and last bit is trivially managed so you reduce the amount of processing required for some possible keys.

I guess it is tricky to develop but it could be funny too, and in the end you will need just to do comparisons of keys since everything else is hardcoded in the lookup table. Of course I'm not sure that the final algorithm will outperform the simple approach but in my opinion it is worth giving it a chance.

Comment: I thought about LUT with 4 Values:
- position of left zero; 
- position of right zero;
- number of one 1's;
- number of two 1's;
With this values I can determine the numbers of others 1's (the requirement is 8bits dimension). But I cannot confirm that this would be faster then simple solution due to bounds checking